# I need some reference about the Fourier-bessel transform

Tags: fourier-transform, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

Hi everyone I'm looking for reference  about the Fourier-bessel transform and translation operator associed with the bessel operator.

Comment: There is some information at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) and [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelTransform.html).